# Spark 1.6.3 rdd.foreach with a broadcast variable cost too much time

Tags: for-loop, apache-spark, rdd

I was using Spark 1.6.3, Scala 2.11.8.

What problem I have is that if i use a **broadcast** variable in rdd.foreach, it cost incredible time, actually I never arrived at "FINISHED".

The main codes are as following

```
val histDS = sc.textFile(args.head)
  .map(_.split("\t"))
  .filter(r => r(17).length > 0 && r(18).length > 0)
  .map(r => HistoryRecord(r(22), r(17).toLong))


val cycle = sc.broadcast[Cycle](Cycle())

for (rec: HistoryRecord <- histDS) {
 // do something, cycle works as global variable
}
```

Maybe it keeps running about 10 minutes, I stop the process, but it works fine if I only print the value in for loop as the following code.

```
for (rec: HistoryRecord <- histDS) {
 println(rec)
}
```

Then, I tried using the following code , use  rdd.**collect()** function, get an Array used for "for" loop.

```
val histDS = sc.textFile(args.head)
  .map(_.split("\t"))
  .filter(r => r(17).length > 0 && r(18).length > 0)
  .map(r => HistoryRecord(r(22), r(17).toLong))
  .collect()
```

Well, this time the code runs ok and finished in about two minutes.

So, anyone know why? And does **collect()** have any performance influence compared to using rdd.**foreach** directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**collect()** will cost much memory resources, described in spark scala API doc

> Running collect requires moving all the data into the application's driver process, and doing so on a very large dataset can crash the driver process with OutOfMemoryError.

**broadcast variable** is best to use for **read only** circumstances, not for **write**, **Accumulator** likes **broadcast** ,can be used for write, but can not fit complex computing.

Principles:
1. **Use map() likes function more**
1. Because RDD runs on worker node, so in them we can not get driver variable, use **broadcast variable** for **READ ONLY**.

Answer (score 0):

A transformation like map and filter will only be executed when you cann action.

For each is not transformation or action of spark. collect is an action and this helps to return the result of the computation back to the driver.

The above way is called lazy evaluation done by spark - In short all transformations done will actually be executed when an action is called.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
.Collect()
```

is action which is provides the result from an RDD [CollectAPi](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@collect():Array[T])

```
foreach(func)
```

is an Action according to the Spark document [Sparkhome](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html)
Run a function func on each element of the dataset. This is usually done for side effects such as updating an [Accumulator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators) or interacting with external storage systems. 
Note: modifying variables other than Accumulators outside of the foreach() may result in undefined behavior.[Foreachexample](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka)